# Edit distance problem( using DP) -- Getting wrong answer

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was solving a minimum Edit Distance problem where I had to find the minimum number of insertions, deletions, and replacements required to convert one string into another one. I used the bottom-up approach to form an array and then proceed further. But I failed on a test case where I had to convert 'short' to 'ports'( my output was 2, the expected output is 3).

Here's my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::min;

int min1( int x, int y, int z );
int edit_distance(const string &str1, const string &str2);

int min1( int x, int y, int z ){
  return min( min(x,y),z);
}

int edit_distance(const string &str1, const string &str2) {

  int m = str1.length();
  int n = str2.length();
  vector <vector <int> > D ( (m+1) , vector <int> (n+1) ); 

  for( size_t i{1} ; i<=m ; ++i ){
    for( size_t j{1} ; j<= n ; ++j ){
      if( j==0){
         D.at(i).at(j) = i;
      }
      else if( i==0 ){
         D.at(i).at(j) = j;
      }
      else if(str1[i-1] == str2[j-1]){
        D.at(i).at(j)= D.at(i-1).at(j-1);
      }
      else{
      D.at(i).at(j) =1+ min1( D.at(i-1).at(j) , D.at(i).at(j-1) , D.at(i-1).at(j-1) );
      }
    }
  }

  return D.at(m).at(n);
}
int main() {
  string str1;
  string str2;
  std::cin >> str1 >> str2;
  std::cout << edit_distance(str1, str2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Please help me with the problem in my code..

Comment: Did you try to debug your program and see why its output differs? Other than that +1 for using STL stuff, I see too many C-like C++ here for these types of questions.

Comment: I think you have some error with index.

Comment: @SHP But I can't see it.

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar Something llike `i`  from 1 to m, but you wrote like `if (i == 0)`, which will never happen. Also, index of a string is from 0 to m - 1, access string[m] may trigger some bad things like exception.